ASCII not exporting properly when using Tux Guitar
I was trying to export my (.tg) file into the ASCII format, but the techniques (like hammer-ons, pull offs, etc) are not appearing onto the text file. Is there a certain reason for this? And is there anyway that I can fix it?

But this is the ASCI for this

Why isn't the slide between 10 and 14 appearing? And this is not only for slides, but also for hammer ons, pulloffs, etc.

When dealing with software issues, one of the first things to do is to check the manual and eventually query the support, including forums, if any: in this case, start by searching in the original discussion forum. You may consider posting an issue on their new repository (started after the original web site went dead and the author stopped answering) and properly asking for help (including the TuxGuitar version you're using and eventually attaching the file you're having issues with).

I’m voting to close this question because without an appropriate context it's not possible to provide a proper answer, since it may even be caused by a software bug or misuse of the program.
